# Data not getting standardized in python

Tags: python, arrays, standardized

I wanted to standardize my array data, but it's showing zero values

This is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
input_data = (10,168,74,0,0,38,0.537,34)
input_data_as_numpy_array = np.array(input_data)
print(input_data_as_numpy_array)

input_data_reshaped = input_data_as_numpy_array.reshape(1,-1)
print(input_data_reshaped)

standardized_x = sc.fit_transform(input_data_reshaped)

print(standardized_x)
```

Here's the screenshot of the output:

[image]

All the values are zero after standardizing the data, how do I resolve that? I'll appreciate the help.

Comment: Your `input_data_reshaped` is an array of 1 row and 8 columns. The scaler transforms each column so that the column mean is 0 and the variance is 1. So if you have only 1 row, every value will end up as zero (because the mean of each column is just the single value in that column, therefore that single value transforms to zero). Instead, reshape your array to have a single column (and therefore 8 rows).